# How to duplicate the 'squares' in UV editor to affect other faces of an object

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have two 'squares' that define the textures of the faces on an object:

[image]

Is there an easy way to make the smaller 'square' an exact replica of the bigger one above it? Currently I am manually stretching the square along the x-axis.

Comment: I don't know an automatical way to do it, but you can make the manual way easier if you would enable snapping in the _UV Editor_. Just like with meshes in the viewport you can move vertices of the UVs and snap them directly onto the other vertices or at least snap them to the other vertices in X or Y direction for example.